# Cloning from github - how do you find the .git?

Tags: git, github

I want to clone the files from here:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/forms
and it's the first time I use github.
I couldn't understand what .git file should I try and clone?
Many thanks.

Comment: `git clone http://github.com/playframework/Play20.git`

Comment: thanks. is there a way to clone only what i need? the forms?

Comment: There is a link on every repo that gives you the URL for https  ssh and git read only

Comment: It's probably easiest to clone the whole project and copy the parts you want to use from there. Remember to check the project's license and follow what it says as far as your own licensing, attributions, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the repository's URL when you clone a github project. You can find this by clicking on the [Code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20) tab at the top of the project's web page. For the project you linked, the URL is `https://github.com/playframework/Play20.git`. If you are using the command line, you can type

```
git clone https://github.com/playframework/Play20.git
```

to clone the project.